# Jenkins: Unable to execute batch file on a virtual machine

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, continuous-integration, virtual

I created a new free-style software project and under "Configure", I added a "Execute Windows batch command" under the section "Build".

My command in the text-box is as follows:

```
call \\ukvc-miu29-12\c$\Testing1\testing.bat
```

My console output when I try to run my build is as follows:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Run comparison script\workspace
[workspace] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson1649447975658279345.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Run comparison script\workspace>call \\ukvc-miu29-12\c$\Testing1\testing.bat 
Access is denied.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Run comparison script\workspace>exit 1 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Have spent close to two hours looking for a solution online, but I am unable to find one.
New to Jenkins, so any suggestion/s is/are appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess Jenkins runs as another user than the one you're logged in with. So *that* user probably isn't allowed to access that network share (or doesn't have the login credentials cached).

The easiest way of making sure it will work, would probably be to add the same user with the same password that Jenkins runs under to `\\ukvc-miu29-12`.

(As for the `call`, I'm not sure you really need it and I have a vague suspicion that you end up failing the build every time if you use `call` here. The temporary batch Jenkins executes there looks like it *relies* on the fact that control won't return if the batch file was executed successfully. But that's just a guess on my part.)

Comment: Removed the "call" as recommended. Currently it is set to Log on as: Local System account. I have specially given my account permissions to have access to the folder I am trying to access as well. I am able to log on to that machine so I should have the right permissions. :/

Comment: You should probably create a user specifically for Jenkins if you want to go that route. Otherwise you could try using a local batch file that mounts the network share with a given user and password and then executes your remote batch. Something like `net use X: \\ukvc-miu29-12\C$ /user:Foo password & X:\Testing1\testing.bat` might work too, where you currently have the batch file name.

Comment: I've tried even specifying my login details under the Login as section, but I get the following message back. 'System error 86 has occurred.

The specified network password is not correct.

The system cannot find the drive specified.'

Comment: Hmm, this is more promising, I specifically mapped the C drive of that machine as X in My Computer. Then changed the code to be simply X:\Testing1\testing.bat
I get the following error message back now:
[code] Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Run comparison script\workspace
[workspace] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\SSRIKA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson1554397262043659543.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Run comparison script\workspace>X:\Testing1\testing.bat
The system cannot find the drive specified.

Comment: Mapped network drives are per-user. LocalSystem cannot see those you create for you.

Comment: `Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Run comparison script\workspace
[workspace] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson5932531124590766674.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Run comparison script\workspace>net use X: \\ukvc-miu29-12\C$ /user:ASD\JJohn password:aeariqjr   & X:\Testing1\testing.bat
System error 1326 has occurred.

Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

The system cannot find the drive specified.
 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE`

Comment: I get the above mentioned in the console output when I use `net use X: \\ukvc-miu29-12\C$ /user:Foo password & X:\Testing1\testing.bat`

Comment: Read the error message. It contains hints as to what was the problem.

Comment: Fixed the issue, realised I was being silly with the password. However for some reason, when it runs each line of my code, it is unable to access the jarfile :/
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Run comparison script\workspace>java -Duser.timezone='China/Shanghai' -Xms2048m -Xmx4096m -jar cli.jar pa --id 109 -b "BM/Aki Original/" -d "differenceChar/" -c 
Unable to access jarfile cli.jar`